# Why summarize doesn't work even with example functions?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Im trying to compute simple descriptive statistics using the tidiverse package in R. However, when I run the following code, I get an error.
I'm wrapping my head around to figure out why my code doesn't work.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  dplyr::select(GROUP,VAR1, VAR2, VAR3, VAR4) %>% 
  group_by(GROUP) %>% 
  #subset(GROUP!="PUNG") %>% 
  summarize(.cols = everything(), list(Mean=mean, Dev.st=sd))
```

And even the code provided by the helper

```
iris %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("Sepal"), list(mean = mean, sd = sd)))
```

Both produce the following error:

```
Error in `summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = across(everything(), list(Mean =
  mean, Dev.st = sd))`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 0: character(0).
Caused by error in `as_across_fn_call()`:
! Can't convert `fn`, a double vector, to a function.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Oddly it worked some time ago.
What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `summarise` might have been masked by another package that has the same function name. Try `dplyr::summarise`.

Comment: Tried to specify the packages involved and I updated all the packages. Nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the summary function of base R to compute the descriptive stat:

```
summary(df)
```

if you want to use tidyverse then the code would be:

```
df %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric),list(average=mean,standar_deviation=sd)))
```

Comment: I tried iris %>% dplyr::summarise(across(where(is.numeric),list(mean=mean,standar_deviation=sd))) but the same error still pop up.

Comment: What does Caused by error in `as_across_fn_call()`:
! Can't convert `fn`, a double vector, to a function. mean in this case?

Comment: you may have "corrupted" your environment by saving some numbers into a variable named mean. Type the word mean and hit enter. Do you get a value? if so, then you need to reassign mean function
mean<- base::mean